# Given an unsorted Array find maximum value of A[j] - A[i] where j>i..in O(n) time

Tags: java, c, arrays, algorithm

This is an Amazon interview Question.I have solved this problem in O(n) using dynamic 
programming.But I want to know can there be more optimization than **O(n)**

for e.g. suppose below is the array

```
3 7 1 4 2 4 returns 4

5 4 3 2 1 returns Nothing

4 3 2 2 3 returns 1
```

This is the code i have written [Code](http://ideone.com/7Y6Z0)

Comment: I don't see how going from O(n) to O(n log n) would be an optimization.

Comment: But O(nlogn) is worse than O(n)...

Comment: don't you mean in O(n2)?

Comment: Did you use extra space for that O(n) solution ?

Comment: I thought it was Google who's looking for Computer Scientists, and Amazon is looking for Engineers.

Comment: You say you already have an `O(n)` solution. By definition, any `O(n)` is also `O(n logn)`.

Comment: You cannot be an Algorithmist :-(

Comment: @all guys sorry for the typo mistake.

Comment: Better than O(n) here?) I don't think you can escape examining each element at least once, especially given that sample arrays are unsorted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lets say you've got `int A[N]`.

```
int res = -1;
int min_value = A[0];
for(int i=1; i<N; i++) {
    // A[i] - A[j] is maximal, when A[j] is minimal value from {A[0], A[1],.., A[i-1]}
    res = max(res, A[i] - min_value);
    min_value = min(min_value, A[i]);
}
return res;
```

Complexity O(N).

You need to examine N elements so O(N) is best what you can get.

Comment: Do you mean `= min(min_value, A[i])`?

Comment: @Algorithmist, Don't know why this looks so much like [this](http://www.codechef.com/APRIL12/problems/PLAYFIT) problem, which is from an ongoing contest. >.<

Answer (score 7):

> But I want to know can there be more optimization then O(n)

Any of the `n` elements can be part of the solution, and therefore each needs to be examined. Thus, `O(n)` cannot be improved upon.

For completeness, here is a solution that takes `O(n)` time and requires `O(1)` memory:

```
A = [1, 10, 20, -10, 3, 4, 18, 42, 15]

smallest = A[0]
maxdiff = float('-inf')
for x in A[1:]:
  maxdiff = max(maxdiff, x - smallest)
  smallest = min(smallest, x)
print maxdiff
```

Comment: i m sorry for the typo mistake...I was solving some other problem also ,and it got mixed.

Comment: @Algorithmist: No, you can't do better than O(n). Any element can be part of the solution and therefore needs to be examined. There are O(n) elements.

Answer (score 4):

It can't be done better than O(n) because whatever approach you use, you will have to iterate over the array atleast once and that step in itself is O(n). Rest the fight remains only to minimize the constants.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int maxOrderedDiff(int[] A){
    //A[x]-A[y] | x>y
    int min = 0, max = 0;
    int less = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<A.length; i++){
        if(A[less]>A[i]){
            less = i;
        }
        if(A[i]-A[min]>A[max]-A[min] || A[i]-A[less] >A[max]-A[min]){
            max=i;
            if(A[less]<A[min])
                min = less;
        }
    }

    return max>min? A[max]-A[min]: -1;
}//maxOrderedDiff
```

TEST WITH:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] A = {{3, 7, 1, 4, 2, 4},{5, 4, 3, 2,1},{4, 3, 2, 2, 3}};

    for(int[] B: A)
        System.out.format("%s :: %d%n", Arrays.toString(B), maxOrderedDiff(B));
}
```